# Problema al obtener fecha con jDateChooser

Tags: java, prepared-statements, jdatechooser

tengo un `jDateChooser` del cual quiero obtener la fecha pero me es imposible, para recuperarla tengo el siguiente fragmento:

```
Date date = jDateChooser_caducidad.getDate();
```

en teoria deberia de funcionar pero lo que me recoge del `jDateChooser` es un `null` y por mas que busco no encuentro soucion, a alguien le a pasado y sabe como solucionarlo.

El codigo es el siguiente

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;

 // metodo para añadir los articulos junto con los datos
    public void insertaAriticulos() throws ParseException {

        //Cargamos conexión
        Conexion conectar = new Conexion();
        //Pasamos el objeto Connection 

        Connection connection = conectar.getConection();
        //Creamos un objeto de la clase Statement
        PreparedStatement pstm;

        //Creamos la sentencia sql.
        String sql = "INSERT INTO articulos (nombre_articulo, categoria, fecha_caducidad) VALUES (?,?,?)";

        // capturamos los datos en variables
        String nombre = jTextField_nombre.getText();
        String categoria = jComboBox_categoria.getSelectedItem().toString();
        // pasos para obtener la fecha actual
         fecha1 = jDateChooser_caducidad.getDate();
        //Ejecutamos la sentencia sql
        try {
            //Establecemos la comunicación con la BD
            pstm = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            //Le pasamos al objeto de ResultSet el resultado de ejecutar la sentencia sql
            pstm.setString(1, nombre);
            pstm.setString(2, categoria);
            pstm.setDate(3, (java.sql.Date) fecha1);

            //hacemos la actualizacion
            int actualizacion = pstm.executeUpdate();
            // comprobamos que se guardan correctamente
            if (actualizacion > 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los datos se guardaron correctamente");
                // vaciamos los campos
                jTextField_nombre.setText("");
                // pasamos el foco al nombre de nuevo
                jTextField_nombre.requestFocus();

            }

            //Cerramos las conexiones.
            pstm.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al guardar.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Buenas, por favor pon el código fuente, sin el nos es imposible ayudarte.

Comment: import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date; // pasos para obtener la fecha actual
         fecha1 = jDateChooser_caducidad.getDate();

Comment: Mejor edita tu pregunta y añade ahí el código

Comment: ¿Estas seleccionando la fecha o simplemente introduciendola a mano?

Comment: estoy seeccionandola a traves de jDateChooser, a mano no introduzco nada, y a traves de ese metodo deberia de obtenerla, pero me captura un null

Comment: Cuando crees el `jDateChooser` prueba a hacerle un `.setDate(new Date())`

Comment: nada me sigue devolviendo un null y no se por que

Comment: ¿Estas generandolo en codigo o mediante el plugin de NetBeans?

Comment: el probema esque no captura la fecha en la variable date por medio del metodo getDate()

Comment: en codigo, lo tengo implementado por medio de un .jar que descargue y agregue a la paleta de Swin de netbeans

Comment: codigo no utilizo ningun plugin

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el codigo que lo crea?

Comment: perdonoa no lo creo a codigo no te entendi bien lo arrastro desde la paleta de netbeans de componentes es decir,utilizao un beans un componente

Comment: Vale, una de las propiedades del componente (una vez arrastrado) te tiene que permitir definir el Date inicial.

Comment: Buenas de nuevo, ayer no se que le paso pero esta mañana borre el componente y volvi a `poner un jDateChooser nuevo y funciona, captura la fecha con el metodo getDate()  lo siento por el tiempo perdido y gracias

Comment: De casualidad te refieres a la clase JDateChooser de la librería [tag:jcalendar]?

Answer (score 1):

creo que si usas este código  `fecha1 = jDateChooser_caducidad.getDate();` obtiene un salida de fecha incompatible con la BD, debido a que obtienes un null. además no inicializas la variable fecha1.

antes de nada te sugiero que le des dateFormatString a tu jdateChooser desde la propiedades de jdateChooser por defecto esta asi d/MM/yyyy, cambiala de esta manera yyyy-MM-dd

ahora puede probar formatear de esta manera la fecha

```
 String fecha1 =((JTextField)jDateChooser_caducidad.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
```

de esta manera obtendrás un fecha con formato valido para tu BD

ya obtenido una fecha valida podrá enviar la fecha a la BD.

Answer (score 0):

Le veo un problema a tu código y es que no puedes convertir con *casteo* de `java.util.Date` a `java.sql.Date`.

Para ello usa:

```
java.util.Date fechaActual= new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
java.sql.Date fechaSql= java.sql.Date.valueOf(fechaActual.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate());
```

Referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date